# How does RAID-5 algorithm locate the right device?

Tags: computer-architecture, operating-systems, number-theory, matrices, memory-hardware

Please consider the following diagram of a RAID-5 array (Ignore the gray background):
[image]

Now, given a logical address, how can one return the device number (0-3)?

For example, DeviceByLogicalSector(50) = 0, DeviceByLogicalSector(31)=2.

I've need to implement DeviceByLogicalSector method. I can use space if that's required.

Now, I've noticed the following:
Let's observe only the first $4$ rows; If we have a sector which is above the $P$-diagonal then the formula is: $\frac{(\text{logical_addr} \mod 12)}{4}$. And if the sector is below the diagonal then we need to add $1$.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Extracted from: [HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171800/hp-smartarray-raid5-recovery-on-linux)

```
// Assume all indexes are zero-based.
// Algorithm = Left-Asym

ChunkIndex = LogicalSector / SectorsPerChunk
StripeIndex = ChunkIndex / (DiskCount - 1)

ParityDisk = (DiskCount - 1) - ((StripeIndex / ParityDelay) % DiskCount)

DataDisk = (LogicalSector % (SectorsPerChunk * (DiskCount - 1))) / SectorsPerChunk
If ParityDisk <= DataDisk:
    DataDisk = DataDisk + 1

PhysicalSector = (LogicalSector / SectorsPerChunk) * (DiskCount - 1)
PhysicalSector = PhysicalSector * SectorsPerChunk
PhysicalSector = PhysicalSector + (LogicalSector % SectorsPerChunk)
```

Comment: Thanks but we're looking for explanatory answers, not lumps of code.

Comment: David - that lump of code breaks down the problem by solving key values (ChunkIndex, StripeIndex, ParityDisk, DataDisk and PhysicalSector) and then showing how they are used to solve the issue. Basically, I can't particlarly explain any further - it's just simple math with a splash of logic to tie it all together... Which is by definition what I've written in the first place as an explanation.